# can we use .get() in freemarker template?

Tags: get, freemarker, velocity

I am converting velocity template to Freemarker and came across this condition below

```
=== Velocity Code ===

#if($frm_BenefitIcons.get("$beni.benefitIconNo"))
#set($xxx = $frm_BenefitIcons.get("$beni.benefitIconNo").toString().substring(12).toUpperCase())
#else
#set($xxx = "")
#end
```

and I converted it to freemarker as

```
=== Freemarker Code ===

<#if (frm_BenefitIcons.get("${(beni.benefitIconNo)!}"))??>
<#assign xxx = frm_BenefitIcons.get("${(beni.benefitIconNo)!}")?string?substring(12)?upper_case>
<#else>
<#assign xxx = "">
</#if>
```

is this correct conversion ? apart from using substring.
I am getting output only xxx = "" (which is else part of condition) but not actual value (if part of the condition). Velocity code gives output value for xxx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short (and assuming your `Configuration` uses the default `ObjectWrapper`, or similar), if the argument to `get` is a `String`, you should write `frm_BenefitIcons[key]`. If `frm_BenefitIcons` is a `java.util.Map`, you can't even call `get`. Unless, you explicitly tell that you want to call the Java API of the object: `frm_BenefitIcons?api.get(key)`. This last is also how you could look up with a non-`String` key (as the `[]` operator doesn't support that).

As of the conversion, I think this will be cleaner:

```
<#assign benefitIcon = frm_BenefitIcons[beni.benefitIconNo?c]!>
<#assign xxx = (benefitIcon != '')?then(benefitIcon[12..]?upper_case, "")>
```

One critical part there is that where you convert a number (`beni.benefitIconNo` in this case) to a string, you must use `?c`, not `?string`, nor `"${n}"`. Conversion to string without `?c` is subject to localized formatting, like `1234` is possibly formatted to the string `"1,234"`, which will break the lookup for you. `?c` formats for Computer audience, as opposed to for human audience, and so avoids any cultural complication.